# ParametricPlot3D doesn't show

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to plot a given vector (which is not a function) using ParametricPlot3D but couldn't make it show the surface.
I tried using Evaluate, Function and Through but it didn't work.

```
x = {(r0+c Sin[(r-r0)/c]) Cos[t], (r0+c Sin[(r-r0)/c]) Sin[t], c (Cos[(r-r0)/c]-1)};
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[x, {r, r0 - w/2, r0 + w/2}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}], {{w, 1},
   0.5, 2}, {{r0, 1}, 0.5, 2}, {{c, 1}, 0.1, 10}]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better (and more readable) to make clear definitions:

First:

```
f[r0_, r_, c_, 
   t_] := {(r0 + c Sin[(r - r0)/c]) Cos[
     t], (r0 + c Sin[(r - r0)/c]) Sin[t], c (Cos[(r - r0)/c] - 1)};
```

Then:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  f[r0, r, c, t], {r, r0 - w/2, r0 + w/2}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}], {{w, 1}, 
  0.5, 2}, {{r0, 1}, 0.5, 2}, {{c, 1}, 0.1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will do that.
Apart from readability, can you tell why mine didn't work?

Comment: `Manipulate` is like Module, so the variables get "localized", so you have to pass them "outside" to your `x` (resp. my `f`)